# How to exclude zeros from a list

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

I am writing a linear program in python `gurobi` and I am trying to create some constraints only including a multiplication of the elements of two lists but excluding the zeros. More specifically: `A` is a list that contains only positive or zero elements, `B` is a list with binary variables demonstrating the positions where there are zeros in A list, for example:

```
A=[1,2,0,3,0]
B=[1,1,0,1,0]
```

I want to add some constraints including only the `A[x]*B[x]` but not the zeros.

Anybody has any idea how this could be done?

Comment: something like `A = [a for a in A if a]` ? not sure. what's your input/expected output?

Comment: Do you actually want to remove the zeros or just not use them when running calculations like in your example above?

Comment: Jean-Frenacois thanks for the advice, but this does not work. I am writing in gurobi meaning that an if statement is not possible. pshep i just want to not use them when creating other constraints, completely ignore them. I will iterate through all elements of those two lists and i just want to create the constraints only for the items that are non zero

Comment: The practical formulation depends on the details. Usually we can use some implications or some big-M formulation.

Comment: You should clarify what are data and what are decision variables; you don't need a constraint for the obvious relationship of x[i] = 1 if and only if a[i] > 0.

Comment: Yes, more specifically: A is a decision variable. B is a binary(again decision variable) that depends only on whether A[i] is 0 or >0. Therefore, i need to create constraints using B[i] but only for i which are not zero. that is only because in the constraints i have to formulate a minimization of a variable, but only take the minimum from the non zero B[i], else i will always get 0 as the min(B[i]*C[i]), where C[i] is just data.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,0,3,0])
B=np.array([1,1,0,1,0])
C=A[B>0]
```

The `C` is `array([1, 2, 3])`

Also, similarly to what @Jean-François Fabre suggested, you can just do

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([1,2,0,3,0])
C=A[A!=0]
```

Comment: I don't think i can make it work. Thanks though for the tip

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove 0 from the list of `int` you can do :

```
A=[1,2,3,0,4,3,0,0,0,1]
C=[i for i in A if i!=0]
```

output :

```
C=[1,2,3,4,3,1]
```

Comment: might fail for `False` or `0.0`

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
A = [1, 2, 0, 3, 0]
B = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
mul = [a*b for a,b in zip(A,B) if a != 0 and b !=0]
print mul
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am writing in gurobi, which means if or != is not allowed :). Thanks again though